# VB6 DomDocument.SetProperty missing

Tags: vb6, domdocument, msxml

I am having to make an old VB6 application run on Windows 10. The issue was that the reference to DomDocument40 is not part of Windows 10 (or 7 i believe) and instead uses DomDocument60 (part of the msxml6.dll).
The line was:

```
Dim oXMLDom1 As New DOMDocument40
```

To ensure backward compatibility i believe it is better to use DomDocument which will automatically use the appropriate version on the system. Is this correct?

So my line is now:

```
Dim oXMLDom1 As New DOMDocument
```

However, now when I try to run the application i get the compiler error *'Method or data member not found.'* This relates to the following line (which I now see setProperty is not supported in msxml6):

```
oXMLDom1.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
```

Can anyone tell me firstly if using DomDocument instead of DomDocument40 is the recommended solution. And if so what I should do about setProperty no longer being available?

I know the best solution is to write this in almost any other language ;) but that's not an option.

Comment: `SetProperty` is a member of both `DomDocument` and `DomDocument40`. Is your `DOMDocument` in fact `MSXML2.DOMDocument`?

Comment: @GSerg but not of DomDocument60 i believe

Comment: How can I tell what MSXML version it is using? Isnt that the point of just defining DomDocument? The approriate DLL on each system will run!

Comment: You can determine which xml library is being used by viewing the Project-References.  One (or more) of the checked references will be the xml reference being utlized.

Comment: @TheGrovesy `DomDocument60` too. Press F2.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips (i haven't used VB for about 15 years so a bit rusty) So in the References its got both *Microsoft XML, version 2.0* and *Microsoft XML, v6.0* both ticked. So do both need to be ticked? As it appears to (somehow now) be using MSXML2 i believe I can remove all references to setProperty as all calls to this are to set the language to XPath which i believe is default in version 2.0?

Comment: Unless you know what you're doing, you only need 6.0. Then `SetProperty` should compile; whether you need it in the first place I can't really tell, but it won't hurt if you leave it in.

Comment: For MSXML6 - DOMDocument60 is a COM class, that exposes the interface IXMLDOMDocument3, which extends interface IXMLDOMDocument2  (which contains the setProperty method).   IXMLDOMDocument2 extends IXMLDOMDocument.  If the variable referring to the DOMDocument60 object is (probably incorrectly) defined to be of type IXMLDOMDocument - it will not have the setProperty method.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not an answer, but you should be able to safely comment out that line as XPath is the default value from MSXML 4.0 onwards.  If the application is to run on Win10, XPath should be the default.

**EDIT**

After some testing, I think all you need to do is change this:

```
Dim oXMLDom1 As New DOMDocument
```

To this:

```
Dim oXMLDom1 As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
```

The only way I got the SetProperty method to fail like that was explicitly adding a reference to `Microsoft XML, version 2.0` and declaring the object without `MSXML2` (that also fails, as the class name is `MSXML` for that version).  I tested this adding references from `Microsoft XML, v2.6` to `Microsoft XML, v6.0` and it works without problems for all of them.  Please notice that I did all this testing on an XP machine, as I have no way to test it on a Win10 PC right now, but it should work fine.

Comment: Thats partly the problem we're facing. We still have some customers using Windows XP. Therefore is needs to work from XP all the way to Windows 10.